# subprocess32.Popen crashes (cpu 100%)

Tags: bash, python-2.7, subprocess

I have been trying to use `subprocess32.Popen` but this causes my system to crash (CPU 100%). So, I have the following code:

```
import subprocess32 as subprocess

for i in some_iterable:
    output = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/sh/file/script.sh',i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5]],shell=False,stdin=None,stdout=None,stderr=None,close_fds=True)
```

Before this, I had the following:

```
import subprocess32 as subprocess
for i in some_iterable:
    output subprocess.check_output(['/path/to/sh/file/script.sh',i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5]])
```

.. and I had no problems with this - except that it was dead slow.

With Popen I see that this is fast - but my CPU goes too 100% in a couple of secs and the system crashes - forcing a hard reboot.

I am wondering what it is I am doing which is making Popen to crash?

On Linux,Python2.7 if that helps at all.

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is your script doing, and how big is `some_iterable` in this case? `check_output()` waits for each process to finish, `Popen()` does not, so you're spawing multiple parallel processes. So if your script consumes a lot of resources (running out of memory) that may be the reason the system becomes unstable.

Comment: `some_iterable` is about 2 million entries.. I understand what you are saying, but how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to start 2 millon processes at once, which is blocking your system.

A solution would be to use a Pool to limit the maximum number of processes that can run at a time, and wait for each process to finish. For this cases where you're starting subprocesses and waiting for them (IO bound), a thread pool from the [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) module would do:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
import subprocess32 as subprocess

def run_script(args):
    args = ['/path/to/sh/file/script.sh'] + args
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, close_fds=True)
    # wait for exit and return exit code
    # or use check_output() instead of Popen() if you need to process the output.
    return process.wait()

# use a pool of 10 to allow at most 10 processes to be alive at a time
threadpool = mp.Pool(10)

# pool.imap or pool.imap_unordered should be used to avoid creating a list
# of all 2M return values in memory
results = threadpool.imap_unordered(run_script, some_iterable)
for result in results:
    ... # process result if needed
```

I've left out most of the arguments to `Popen` because you are using the default values anyway. The size of the pool should probably be in the range of your available CPU cores if your script is doing comutational work, if it's doing mostly IO (network access, writing files, ...) then probably more.

Comment: how do I pass arguments to `run_script` within `threadpool.imap_unordered(run_script, some_iterable)`? Secondly, I use a csv reader to read the 2million entries, and I have something like ` reader = csv.reader(open(filex),delimiter='|')
 for row in reader:` In this case what would `some_iterable` be? Previosuly, I passed on each `row` to the Popen process.. Not sure how I can achieve this now with your idea..

Comment: I have tried to implement this here: http://pastebin.com/jKka6cHG but ofcoz this is wrong... Not sure how to invoke `threadpool` with `runscript`...

Comment: The `map` functions take a function to run and an iterable of arguments and call that function for each item in the list. So you don't need to call the function in a loop, you can just pass the `reader` as the argument iterator, like [this](http://pastebin.com/WCRDCzfB)